# Mooc Helsinki Part 1 Week 4 Exercise 18 Java

Tags: java

The program described here should be implemented in the class PersonalInformationCollection. NB! Do not modify the class PersonalInformation.

After the user has entered the last set of details (they enter an empty first name), exit the repeat statement.

Then print the collected personal information so that each entered object is printed in the following format: first and last names separated by a space (you don't print the identification number). An example of the working program is given below:

```
Sample output
First name: Jean
Last name: Bartik
Identification number: 271224
First name: Betty
Last name: Holberton
Identification number: 070317
First name:

Jean Bartik
Betty Holberton
```

The `PersonalInformation` class:

```
public class PersonalInformation {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String identificationNumber;

    public PersonalInformation(String firstName, String lastName, String identificationNumber) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.identificationNumber = identificationNumber;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getIdentificationNumber() {
        return identificationNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName + " (" + this.identificationNumber + ")";
    }
}
```

My solution which I can only print all values instead of only Firstnames and the Lastnames from the array:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<PersonalInformation> infoCollection = new ArrayList<>();


        while (true) {
            System.out.println("First name: ");
            String firstName = scanner.nextLine();
            if (firstName.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Last name: ");
            String lastName = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Identification number: ");
            String identificationNumber = scanner.nextLine();

            infoCollection.add(new PersonalInformation(firstName, lastName, identificationNumber));


        }
        System.out.println(infoCollection);


    }


}
```

I need to modify the code. I am a beginner, an explanatory suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you want to know? What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: I want to know how to modify the code in a way that I can pull the firstNames and lastNames and avoid printing the Identification number.

Comment: How would you enter a first name that contains a space, such as Moon Unit Zappa? And no, Unit is not a middle name.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
System.out.println(infoCollection);
```

you´ll have

```
infoCollection.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        ArrayList<PersonalInformation> infoCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("First name: ");
            String firstName = scanner.nextLine();
            if (firstName.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Last name: ");
            String lastName = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Identification number: ");
            String identificationNumber = scanner.nextLine();
            infoCollection.add(new PersonalInformation(firstName, lastName, identificationNumber));

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < infoCollection.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(infoCollection.get(i).getFirstName() + " "
                    + infoCollection.get(i).getLastName());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the while statement, to print just the first and last names, try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < infoCollection.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(infoCollection.get(i).getFirstName() + " " + infoCollection.get(i).getLastName());
}
```

Comment: This is *exactly* the code (or, rather, part of it) from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62145626/10871073), posted some time ago.

Comment: my bad - did not notice that - i'll remove my post

Answer (score -1):

```
for (PersonalInformation personalInformation: infoCollection) {
    System.out.println(personalInformation.getFirstName() + ' ' + 
personalInformation.getLastName());
}
```